# How can I list Content Types as checkbox in Profile types for Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-content-types

In drupal user registration, Users should be able to choose the types which they want to subscribe to. So, how can I list Content Types (node types) in Custom Profile Registration Type?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvWd2.png

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve all Content Types with `node_type_get_names()` function.
So, in hook_form_alter add:

```
$form['ct'] = array(
  '#type' => 'checkboxes',
  '#options' => node_type_get_names(),
  '#title' => t('What standardized tests did you take?'),
);
```

Comment: You are great, it works perfect. How can I skip first Content Type while listing?

Comment: You better don't skip it but unset a unneeded one:

$options = node_type_get_names();
unset($options['article']);

Where 'article' is the Content Type you want to delete.

Comment: One more question:

How to insert into a table these (selected checkboxes) values and read in future? 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26039974/how-to-insert-into-database-drupal-custom-fields