# How to insert into database Drupal Custom Fields

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-content-types

I retrieve content types with the following code

```
$form['ct'] = array(
  '#type' => 'checkboxes',
  '#options' => node_type_get_names(),
  '#title' => t('Hangi tür içerikler hakkında bilgi almak istersiniz?'),
);
```

And It gives the following output

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOfS6.png

And when I press **Create new Account** button, the POST Array is so  :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BtxhC.png

My Question is How can I insert into database these values and read?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of saving this data and associates with user ID ($user->uid).

1. Adding a new field for users from 'admin/config/people/accounts/fields'. Say the new field name is 'ct' and it is a list type field. In hook form_alter you can assign this options to 'ct'. Drupal will take care of saving the data.
2. You can create separate table to keep this information and use db_insert function in hook hook_user_update. To retrieve this information you need to use db_query in hook_user_load.

Comment: For first solution, I added ct from Admin Panel but I don't know how to assign. I created form_alter function, what do I need write in it?

Comment: In form_alter add :
$form['#submit'][] = "function_to_submit_data_in_database"; and add your logic to function name "function_to_submit_data_in_database". Be sure your function execute first before default submit handler.

Comment: `function MY_MODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

  switch ($form_id) {
    case 'user_profile_form':
      $form['field_ct']['und']['#options'] = node_type_get_names();
      break;
}
}`

Comment: Great, it shows me the selected boxes on profile view, but when I click edit profile link checkboxes do not come as selected. How can I fix?

Comment: My friend found the solution

$form['field_ct']['und']['#title'] = "Hangi Tür içerikler hakkında bilgi almak istersiniz?";    
 $form['field_ct']['und']['#options'] = node_type_get_names();

$getarr=array();
foreach($form['#user']->field_ct['und'] as $bb){
 $getarr[]=$bb['value'];
 }
 $form['field_ct']['und']['#default_value'] = $getarr;
   
 break; 
 }